# Invoke-DbaQuery in a Loop With Just One Set of Headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm running `Invoke-DBAQuery` with `Format-Table` in a loop to get system configs from various servers. Each run is writing out its own headers though. Using `-HideTableHeaders` means I get no headers at all. How can I get just the first set of headers and then not for the rest? All servers are running the same version of SQL so there won't be additional headers for different servers.

```
$Servers = 'ServerA','ServerB'
Clear-Variable -Name Data 
$Data

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) 
{
$Data += Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Server -Query "Declare   @List Varchar(Max)

Select      @List = Coalesce(@List + ',', '') + Concat('[',Name,']')
From        sys.Configurations
Order By    Name



Declare @SQL Varchar(Max) =
'Select     @@ServerName as Server
            --,Row_Number() Over (Order By GetDate()) As RowNum
            ,*
From        (
            Select      Name
                        ,Value 
            From        sys.configurations
            ) sq
    Pivot   (
            Max(Value)
            For Name In (' + @List + ')
            ) piv'

Exec (@SQL)" | Format-Table #-HideTableHeaders
}


$Data
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `-As` parameter? e.g.: `@('ServerA','ServerB') | %{ Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $_ -Query $Query -As 'PSObject' }`? Ref: [Invoke-DbaQuery](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery)

Comment: That didn't work as i'd have liked, it returned 2 lists of the values. I didn't know about -As though (new-ish to PoSh) and the tab suggestions suggested DataTable. Using that and moving the format-table to the end has worked a treat though!

`Exec (@SQL)" -As DataTable
}

$Data | Format-Table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed `-as DataTable` on the `Invoke-DbaQuery` and then move the `Format-Table` to the end, thanks @AlwaysLearning for pointing me at `-As`

```
$Servers = 'ServerA','ServerB'
Clear-Variable -Name Data 
$Data

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) 
{
$Data += Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Server -Query "Declare   @List Varchar(Max)

Select      @List = Coalesce(@List + ',', '') + Concat('[',Name,']')
From        sys.Configurations
Order By    Name



Declare @SQL Varchar(Max) =
'Select     @@ServerName as Server
            --,Row_Number() Over (Order By GetDate()) As RowNum
            ,*
From        (
            Select      Name
                        ,Value 
            From        sys.configurations
            ) sq
    Pivot   (
            Max(Value)
            For Name In (' + @List + ')
            ) piv'

Exec (@SQL)" -As DataTable
}


$Data | Format-Table
```